# If exists select column from another table

Tags: sql

I need help solving this problem. I have two tables:

Table 1

```
MonthYear   Code    Value
jan/18      4169    50
jan/18      4102    95
```

Table 2

```
Date    Code    Value
jan/18  4102    30
jan/18  4102    10
jan/18  4102    15
jan/18  4102    40
```

I need to make a query that returns the value field of table 1 if there is no code in table 2 or that returns the value field of table 2 if there is code in table 2.

For example:

```
MonthYear   Code    Value
jan/18      4169    50
jan/18      4102    30
jan/18      4102    10
jan/18      4102    15
jan/18      4102    40
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Code NOT IN (SELECT Code FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this as:

```
select t2.date, t2.code, t2.value
from table2 t2
union all
select t1.date, t1.code, t1.value
from table2 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.date = t2.date and t1.code = t2.code);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `coalesce` :

```
select t1.MonthYear, 
       coalesce(t2.Code,t1.Code) as Code, 
       coalesce(t2.value,t1.value) as value
  from table2 t2
  right outer join table1 t1
    on ( t2.Code = t1.Code );
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1ddd13/3)

P.S. I chose ***PostGreSQL*** as *DB* for the Demo, you may use this SQL also for ***Oracle***, ***SQL-Server*** or ***MySQL***.

Actually, you'd better replacing keyword `right` with `full` in the SQL as :

```
select coalesce(t2.MonthYear,t1.MonthYear) as MonthYear, 
       coalesce(t2.Code,t1.Code) as Code, 
       coalesce(t2.value,t1.value) as value
  from table2 t2
  full outer join table1 t1
    on ( t2.Code = t1.Code );
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo 2***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4d1d9/6)

except for ***MySQL***, since there occurs an alternative case in which ***the code exists in Table2 but not Table1***, `full outer join` provides the solution( special thanks to @Error_2646 ).

Comment: What if the code exists in Table2 but not Table1 - won't this drop those records?

Comment: @Error_2646 we can manage it by replacing `right` with `full` for `oracle` or `postgreSQL`or `SQL-Server`, but for this question there's no database limitation and for this data set, this SQL satisfy the desired results.